# How to make first row turn into second level MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have an existing DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     1   |   1   |   1   |   2   |   2   |   2   |   2
 --------------------------------------------------------
  | abc  |  def  |  ghi  |  jkl  |  mno  |  pqr  |  stu
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
```

I've been trying this for sometime, but no success.

The repeated ones and twos are already a one level MultiIndex.
I know that if I add another level they will merge together, but having a hard time transforming that first row into the second level of the MultiIndex.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

desired output:

```
             1           |               2             
  | abc  |  def  |  ghi  |  jkl  |  mno  |  pqr  |  stu
 --------------------------------------------------------
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
  | 1.00 |  2.00 |  3.00 |  4.00 |  5.00 |  6.00 |  7.00
```

any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution proposed by *Jezrael* requires some corrections:

1. `df.columns` and `df.iloc[0]` should be **together** the first
   argument of `from_arrays`, not two separate arguments.
2. The source of the second level of *MultiIndex* (*df.iloc[0]*)
   should be supplemented with *.values*. Otherwise this *MultiIndex* level
   inherits name (*0*) - the index value of row *0*.
3. The resulting *MultiIndex* should be substituted to `df.columns`,
   not to the whole `df`.

So the whole solution should be:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, df.iloc[0].values])
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and then filter out first row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with indexing:

```
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.columns, df.iloc[0])
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Comment: I had to do just a few changes, will post and answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to jezrael's answer. The idea was correct, just a few changes to make it work. Thanks jezrael.

```
    index = np.array([df.columns.values, df.iloc[0].values])

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)
    df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Comment: small correction ..

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index)

Answer (score 1):

Using  `T` and `set_index`

```
df.T.set_index(0,append=True).T
```